# How to print data into a specific json format in python

Tags: python, json

How can I print the following data

55550000000
175600000000
55290000000
143100000000
55050000000

Like this in python

```
{
value:  55550000000
},
{
value: 175600000000
},
{
value: 55290000000
},
{
value: 143100000000
}
```

My python code is, i guess i am pretty close

```
def sample():
    cpu_sample = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='cpu', limit = 5)

    for each in cpu_sample:
         timetamp = each.timestamp
         volume =  each.counter_volume
         volume_int = int(volume)
         data1 = json.dumps({'value': volume_int}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',',':'))
     print data1
```

this code returns the needed format but without any commas

```
{
    "value":55550000000
}
{
    "value":175600000000
}
{
    "value":55290000000
}
{
    "value":143100000000
}
{
    "value":55050000000
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating each item as a separate JSON string? Just put the dictionaries in a list and convert the whole thing!

Comment: The JSON format itself is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all values into one list and print it using `json.dumps`.
In order to avoid `[` and `]` around the list, you can strip the first and last lines:

```
import json

data = [55550000000, 175600000000, 55290000000, 143100000000, 55050000000]
print json.dumps([{'value': item} for item in data], indent=0)[2:-2]
```

Output:

```
{
"value": 55550000000
}, 
{
"value": 175600000000
}, 
{
"value": 55290000000
}, 
{
"value": 143100000000
}, 
{
"value": 55050000000
}
```